# In Microsoft Access (for 365) is it possible to automatically create a new table depending on entries made in another table?

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design, database-connection, ms-access-2010

I have one table with orders (Orders Table). In the Orders Table I have a checkbox for production to run. When the checkbox is ticked in the run column I would like it to create a new table automatically with a specific format. The new table (Production Table) needs to be filled in with information about the production run. The Production Table needs to be organized so that each item produced (~100 items) has stored data (such as quantity, and conformance status).
What's the best way to have Access collect this information as automatically as possible?

Comment: It's possible but not advisable. Implementing a process that routinely modifies database structure is usually bad design. Why not use a permanent table? Is this a split, multi-user db?

Comment: I'm relatively new to Access and am trying to set it up so it is not currently set up to be split and is only being used by me. I essentially want communication of order details transferred unto a production order. On the production order I also want to collect data from the production run. For each production run there are approx 100 units and each unit has approximately 10 data points collected (quantitative and qualitative). I was going to try to do separate tables for each production run but what you said led me to believe this is not the right way to do it. Any advice for someone new?